# Send email with Spring Boot app in Heroku

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, gmail

I've successfully deployed a Spring Boot app on Heroku. This app should send emails after an user fills a form.

The problem is that, in local it works, but in Heroku the app always throws `AuthenticationFailedException` because it is trying to sign in with my Gmail account from Heroku's server in another country.

My Gmail account does not have two factor authentication and less secure app option is enabled.

How can I solve this? How can my Spring Boot app in a server abroad sign in with my Gmail account from another country?

Comment: If you want to use gmail here is the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61707039/allow-less-secure-apps-on-but-heroku-still-generating-that-error/61709121#61709121?newreg=8ecf18086ee449bc959c6236abbf6563) what works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I solve this?

By not using Gmail. It's not meant for automated, programmatic email delivery.

Instead, use something like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or [Mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/). These services *are* designed for programmatic mail delivery, and [both are available as official Heroku addons with free tiers](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms).

Answer (score 0):

You can set an app password with [google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en). This let you log in with a passcode only for that application.